# Run code when user presses certain key in a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have an ASP.net textbox that the user needs to enter emails. I need to detect when the user types a semi-colon(;) then unhide a textbox and set the focus to that textbox.

Comment: So in your textChanged event handler, check the last byte in textBox1.text to see if it is a semicolon.  If it is, call the method that unhides the other textBox and gives it focus.

Comment: I was going for something instant instead of waiting for a postback but if i cant find anything else this method will work too. Thanks @WDS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: This might seem a little "hacky" and I'm sure there are better ways of doing this.

You can use the `onkeypress` of the textbox, set that to a JavaScript function. In the JavaScript function, programmatically "unhide" and give focus to your other textbox on the client-side. No post-back required.

JavaScript:

```
function checkForSemicolons(event) {
    var txtEmail = document.getElementById("<%= txtEmail.ClientID %>");
    if (event.keyCode === 59) {
        // unhide other textbox and give focus to it
    }
}
```

ASPX:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" onkeypress="checkForSemicolons(event)" runat="server" />
```

Comment: It might be more efficient to use the event to determine what key is pressed that just checking index of because on the next keystroke that will still fire

Comment: Thank you, johnny 5! I've updated my answer to check the key code instead.

Answer (score 0):

OnKeypress event is fired from the client side, so you need do catch that from the client script.

You can use javascript to cause a postback and than send the parameters to the server-side, but usually you can handle all from the client.
On jquery you would have somethig like this:

```js
$("TextboxID").keypress(function(e){
     //do something 
     //If you want to cause a postback use " __doPostBack('EventTaarget','Parameters');"
     //you can capture the key that was pressed on e.keycode (for keycodes list, check: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)

})
```

On the code behind you can add some code to capture this event on page_load.

```html
 Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
   If Me.Request("__EVENTTARGET") Is Nothing Then
       'do something - you can use the Parameter with: Me.Request("__EVENTARGUMENT")
   end if

end sub
```